# thread '<unnamed>' panicked at assertion

Tags: python, dataframe, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

I received an unknown error in Python Polars:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Float64[NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, ...[clip]...
  right: `Float64[NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, ...[clip]...
```

Is this an internal error?

The code that triggers it is:

```py
df.select([
    pl.col('total').shift().ewm_mean(half_life = 10).over('group')
])
```

It's hard for me to ask more because the error is so inscrutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: this issue is now fixed in Polars `0.13.19` and above, and a workaround is no longer needed.

Another temporary way to work around this is to create the result of `shift` with an `over` window in another way.

Let's say we have the following groups, numbered observations, and totals.

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b"],
        "obs": [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3],
        "total": [1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.NaN],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ obs ┆ total │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 1   ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 3   ┆ 4.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2   ┆ 5.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 3   ┆ NaN   │
└───────┴─────┴───────┘
```

The following code will arrive at the same result as the `shift` over the groups:

```py
df = (
    df.sort(["group", "obs"])
    .with_column(pl.col("total").shift().alias("total_shifted"))
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("group").is_first())
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col("total_shifted"))
        .alias("result")
    )
)
df
```

```
shape: (6, 5)
┌───────┬─────┬───────┬───────────────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ obs ┆ total ┆ total_shifted ┆ result │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---           ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64   ┆ f64           ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪════════╡
│ a     ┆ 1   ┆ 1.0   ┆ null          ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 2   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 1.0           ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ 3   ┆ 4.0   ┆ 2.0           ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 1   ┆ 3.0   ┆ 4.0           ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 2   ┆ 5.0   ┆ 3.0           ┆ 3.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ 3   ┆ NaN   ┆ 5.0           ┆ 5.0    │
└───────┴─────┴───────┴───────────────┴────────┘
```

(I've left the intermediate calculations in the dataset for inspection, to show how the algorithm works.)

Notice that the `result` column is the same value you'd obtained from a `shift` over groups.  You can then run your aggregations on the `result` column, without the need for using shift.

```py
df.select([
    pl.col('result').ewm_mean(half_life = 10).over('group')
])
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt this to your particular code, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed looks like a bug.  It's coming from when `shift` is called on an expression that contains `NaN` values in a window function (`over`).

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
        "total": [1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.NaN],
    }
)

df.select([
    pl.col('total').shift().over('group')
])
```

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Float64[4, 5, NaN]`,
 right: `Float64[4, 5, NaN]`', /github/workspace/polars/polars-core/src/series/unstable.rs:39:9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/StackOverflow3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/frame.py", line 4253, in select
    self.lazy()
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/StackOverflow3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazy_frame.py", line 476, in collect
    return self._dataframe_class._from_pydf(ldf.collect())
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Float64[4, 5, NaN]`,
 right: `Float64[4, 5, NaN]`
```

Since you are using the `sum` aggregation, can you use `fill_nan(0)` to work around the issue?  Or do you need to retain the `NaN` value in those cases?

```py
df.select([
    pl.col('total').fill_nan(0).shift().sum().over('group')
])
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ literal │
│ ---     │
│ f64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0     │
└─────────┘
```

I'll create an issue for it on GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately, I greatly simplified the code for the question. The exact aggregation code is above now. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Bug submitted: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3067

Comment: Absolutely.  I'll give another option ...